# Automated build tool for Delphi project

Tags: windows, delphi, build

I have several projects written in Delphi 7 and i am looking for tool which will automate building process (including package creation and upload to the specific ftp location). I would like to find native application (i.e. Rake or fabricate.py are good software but i prefer not to use them this time) without Ant-like xml configurations files

Comment: because d7 doesn't support msbuild, I really recommend finalbuilder for you.

Comment: @Warren: and that qualifies as a native application as it was written in Delphi!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Final Builder](http://www.finalbuilder.com/home.aspx) is the best, and only serious solution for Delphi 7.

The full version will help building, doing your installer, and ftp.

Update: Note that if you do not need a GUI at all, some people simply invoke DCC32 (for delphi 7) or MSBUILD (for Delphi 2007 or later) via batch files, and then run those jobs from Hudson or Jenkins, but where FinalBuilder really shines is when you have to not only run a Delphi msbuild invocation, but other things like building installers, doing file-system actions like copies and moves, etc.

Comment: +1 And native too as it was written in Delphi

Comment: I should point out that I have had some trouble with extremely complex Delphi XE applications not building within Final Builder XE (embarcadero edition).  But they are very good with updates, and it's a great product.

Comment: Also, I should point out that if you had Rad Studio XE you would get a light version of Final Builder free with it.

Comment: @Warren: I've just installed Delphi XE Professional - where is the FinalBuilder (lite) to be found then?

Comment: It was omitted from the Pro edition.

Comment: Final Builder is included in XE and XE2 Enterprise and Architect.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently setting up a build process using R2Build: http://r2build.sourceforge.net/

Feature list (from the source forge page):

- Have Dashboard to monitor all the projects and builds
- Support mutiple Project and Multiple Builds
- Support Build schedule
- Easy to create build flowgraph by drag&drop
- Support the following source control tools: VSS, CVS, Perforce, Clearcase, Subversion, SourroundSCM, MKS
- Support the following development tools: Microsoft Visual Studio 2003/2005/VC6.0/VB6.0, Borland Delphi/C++Builder, Ant, Nant, Jam..
- Support the following installer packaging tool: InstallShield, Inno setup, Nullsoft installer, InstallAware, AdvancedInstaller, Wise Installer
- Support the following automation test tool: NUnit, Rational Robot, Winrunner, QAWizard, test compelete..
- Support help compiler
- Support Mail notification, FTP build result, Winrar, All kinds of file operation, Edit File...
- Open architechture, can easily support more and more new tools by XML config file

Apart from the dashboard to monitor builds, it has an "IDE" to create your build script(s).

Comment: Pro version worths $500.

Comment: @jachguate: and your point is? You do not need to buy the pro version if you don't want to. I certainly am not...

Comment: Sounds like a nice alternative to hudson. These days Hudson is really annoying me.

Comment: Four years later, and I'm still using Hudson, except that I use "Jenkins" which is where most of the original Hudson team went when they got mad at Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Automated Build Studio is now discontinued!

---

*Original answer:*

[Automated Build Studio](http://smartbear.com/products/development-tools/build-management/) by Smart Bear (formerly Automated QA) - the company behind Test Complete and AQ Time.

Comment: +1. I've tried this, and it's not quite at Final Builder's level, but it's really pretty nice piece of software.

Comment: So it's discontinued and they didn't open source it.  Classy. (Not.)

Answer (score 2):

Visual Build Pro from Kinook: http://www.kinook.com/VisBuildPro/
It'll do the build, and lots more. I've automated translation (dictionary merge), code signing, installer creation (Inno), ssh to my web site, and even CD burning with each user getting a customized CD.  It's very powerful stuff.

Comment: Does it only work with MSBuild enabled versions of Delphi (2007 and later) or does it work with Delphi 7 too?

Comment: I think it'll work with any version of Delphi, as it doesn't rely on MSBuild.

Comment: What's with the anonymous downvote haters?  Visual Build Pro is a great product, their support is great, and they're also a SO sponsor.

Comment: +1 I upvoted this because it's a good answer.  Not all tools work equally well for everybody.  Any body who suggests a tool they have used and been happy with, is a pretty good answer, IMHO.

Comment: +1 too... I Agree with @Warren P

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look in [Axial Build](http://www.tecsisinfo.com.br/builder_2009.php).
[Download link](http://dc271.4shared.com/download/uIuJHIQJ/Axial_Build_2009_for_windows.ZIP?tsid=20110402-083528-c71cd8a0) (This download is direct from 4shared drive of the author)

Seems it is only in Portuguese. [Edit] But its free. :) [/Edit]